# How to access Yes/No field of Sharepoint List using Linq?

Tags: linq, sharepoint, casting

I have one list in which there is field with the datatype of Yes/No. I am trying to retrieve data of that field but it is giving me following error :

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.SPQueryable.GetSPFieldValue[T](PropertyMap pm, DataContext dc, SPListItem item, Object entity, JoinPath joinPath) at lambda_method(ExecutionScope , SPListItem ) at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

My query is as follows:

```
var query = (from san in db.San
             select san.IsDeclaredCompleted).ToList();
```

So can anyone suggest me what i am doing wrong?

**NOTE: It is running perfectly on my local system but on server it is giving me error.**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query by appending the ToList() method after db.San

```
var query = from san in db.San.ToList()
            select san.IsDeclaredCompleted;
```

Comment: Check if the .Net type matches with sql datatype. LINQ to SQL throws invalid cast exception when it cannot convert a database type to .Net type

Comment: can u tell me how can i check that??....one more thing....i am trying it in sharepoint 2010

Comment: This thread http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/1c00419a-f616-4556-8098-545f82ff1a3f/ may point you in the right direction as without seeing more of the code or database structure, it will be hard to come to a great solution.